# Trigger action based on value in a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet which contains:
Project Number in Col A
Project Description Col B
Project Manager E-mail address Col C
Date fields Col D and E
Sent status Col F
Date Sent Col G

I want to send an email, once due date has been reached, with the details in the applicable row of the spreadsheet.

I had it running however, it was specific to Cells "A2" and "C2".

I attempted to revise my code to reflect the range in place of "A2" reference but receive a "Compile error syntax error" message referring to this line which is highlighted red:

```
sSendTo = Sheet1.Range.Columns(C) & lLastRow).Value
```

My code is:

```
Sub Jose_SendEmailDueDateReached()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sSendTo As String
    Dim sSendCC As String
    Dim sSendBCC As String
    Dim sSubject As String
    Dim sTemp As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon

    ' Change the following as needed
    sSendTo = Sheet1.Range.Columns(C) & lLastRow).Value
    sSendCC = "Test@123.com"
    sSendBCC = ""
    sSubject = Range("A2").Value & " Progress Photos Due"

    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlDown).Row
    For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
        If Cells(lRow, 6) <> "Sent" Then
            If Cells(lRow, 5) <= Date Then
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = sSendTo
                    If sSendCC > "" Then .CC = sSendCC
                    If sSendBCC > "" Then .BCC = sSendBCC

                    .Subject = sSubject

                    sTemp = "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "The due date has been reached "
                    sTemp = sTemp & "for this project:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    ' Assumes project name is in column B
                    sTemp = sTemp & "    " & Cells(lRow, 2) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "Please take the appropriate"
                    sTemp = sTemp & " action." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "Please forward photos to Test@greenscreen.com.    " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "Thank you."

                    .Body = sTemp
                    ' Change the following to .Send if you want to
                    ' send the message without reviewing first
                    .Display
                End With
                Set OutMail = Nothing

                Cells(lRow, 6) = "Sent"
                Cells(lRow, 7) = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
            End If
        End If
    Next lRow
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    MsgBox ("Clear Stamp")
    Range("F2").ClearContents
    Range("G2").ClearContents
    MsgBox ("Stamp Cleared")

End Sub
```

I am new to VBA.

Comment: your red highlighted line (editor warning) is not typed in correctly ... the brackets are unmatched (1 left bracket ... 2 right brackets)

Comment: you missed OutMail .save  and OutMail.send .

Comment: what mean Sheet1.Range.Columns(C) & lLastRow).Value?

Comment: 1. Edit your question and put a dummy email address; 2. "sSendTo = Sheet1.Range.Columns(C) & lLastRow).Value" should be moved after "lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlDown).Row" so lLastRow is initialized; 3. Change the "sSendTo = ..." line to "sSendTo = Sheet1.Cells(lLastRow, "C").Value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an email once a value has been reached, you can use the code/concept below.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Cell A1 is changed" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail9.htm

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with: `sSendTo = Sheet1.Range.Columns(C) & lLastRow).Value`

- `Sheet1` looks like a variable, but you haven't declared it, so I presume you're referring to the worksheet called "Sheet1", i.e. `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`
- `Columns(C)`: again `C` looks like a variable, but you haven't declared it, so I presume you're referring to column "C" (i.e. the third column in the worksheet)
- You have only one opening bracket `(` (before `C`) but you have two closing brackets `)` (one after `C`, one after `lLastRow`)
- `.Range.Columns(C) & lLastRow` isn't really correct, but I know what you're trying to do.

It should be:
`sSendTo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lLastRow, "C").Value`

Or:
`sSendTo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lLastRow).Value`

Tip: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of every module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Jose_SendEmailDueDateReached()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sSendTo As String
    Dim sSendCC As String
    Dim sSendBCC As String
    Dim sSubject As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon

    vDB = Sheet1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For lRow = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)

        If vDB(irow, 6) <> "Sent" Then
            If vDB(lRow, 5) <= Date Then
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                sSendTo = vDB(i, 4)
                sSubject = vDB(i, 1) & " Progress Photos Due"

                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = sSendTo
                    'If sSendCC > "" Then .CC = sSendCC
                    'If sSendBCC > "" Then .BCC = sSendBCC
                    .Subject = sSubject

                    sTemp = "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "The due date has been reached "
                    sTemp = sTemp & "for this project:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    ' Assumes project name is in column B
                    sTemp = sTemp & "    " & Cells(lRow, 2) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "Please take the appropriate"
                    sTemp = sTemp & " action." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "Please forward photos to BAS.HSGReporting@hpw.qld.gov.au.  " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    sTemp = sTemp & "Thank you."

                    .Body = sTemp
                    ' Change the following to .Send if you want to
                    ' send the message without reviewing first
                    .Save
                    .Send
                    .Display
                End With
                Set OutMail = Nothing

                vDB(lRow, 6) = "Sent"
                vDB(lRow, 7) = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
            End If
        End If
    Next lRow
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Sheet1.Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Within the above revised code I am unable to get values "Sent" 
and "Email sent on "now"" to appear in columns 6 and 7 within the vDB range.Lines of code are:  
                vDB(lRow, 6) = "Sent"
                vDB(lRow, 7) = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
All assistance greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the outlook section of the code instead. Adding `& Cells(lRow, 3)` in the `.to =` line

```
 With OutMail
'Adds values in column C as recipients 
                .To = sSendTo & Cells(lRow, 3)
                If sSendCC > "" Then .CC = sSendCC
                If sSendBCC > "" Then .BCC = sSendBCC
'Includes project name (column B) in the Subject
                .Subject = sSubject & " - " & Cells(lRow, 2)
```

This also places the name of your project into the subject.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim sSendTo As String
Dim sSendCC As String
Dim sSendBCC As String
Dim sSubject As String
Dim sTemp As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

' Change the following as needed
sSendTo = ""
sSendCC = ""
sSendBCC = "YourEmail@you.com"
sSubject = "Due date reached"

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
    If Cells(lRow, 6) <> "S" Then
        If Cells(lRow, 5) <= Date Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
'Adds values in column C as recipients 
                .To = sSendTo & Cells(lRow, 3)
                If sSendCC > "" Then .CC = sSendCC
                If sSendBCC > "" Then .BCC = sSendBCC
'Includes project name (column B) in the Subject
                .Subject = sSubject & " - " & Cells(lRow, 2)

                sTemp = "Hello!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                sTemp = sTemp & "The due date has been reached "
                sTemp = sTemp & "for this project:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                ' Assumes project name is in column B
                sTemp = sTemp & "    " & Cells(lRow, 2) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                sTemp = sTemp & "Please take the appropriate "
                sTemp = sTemp & "action." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                sTemp = sTemp & "Thank you!" & vbCrLf

                .Body = sTemp
                ' Change the following to .Send if you want to
                ' send the message without reviewing first
                .Display
            End With
            Set OutMail = Nothing

            Cells(lRow, 6) = "S"
            Cells(lRow, 7) = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
        End If
    End If
Next lRow
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```